# Oracle products or not?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Is **Read Consistency Rollback segments** a feature of Oracle products or a general feature of RDBMS?

Same question but this time regarding **Storing/Tablespaces**?

Lastly are **blocks, extents and segments** a feature of Oracle or databases in general?

Many thanks in advance to your replies!

Comment: is that a hidden oracle survey? :)

Comment: No and no, its examnable materials for my course, however my lecturer has a fetish for Oracle, however she has now come out and said that specific Oracle tech is not part of the exam. It was just included to demo RDBM systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Read consistency** is an attribute (from my perspective a requirement) of a transactional database.

**Rollback segments** are (in a nutshell) how Oracle supports transactions. Btw. it's not called rollback segement any longer. It's called UNDO nowadays

**Tablespaces** are nothing unique to Oracle. Most (if not all) large scale DBMS support that.

All DBMS I know access the filesystem by **blocks**. A block (sometimes called a page) is usually the smallest (storage) unit a DBMS can read or write.

**Extents** are nothing unique to Oracle. Other DBMS just have different names for that.

**Segments** is a name I have only come across in the Oracle world. But I guess the concept exists in any major DBMS in some way or the other.

Comment: Sweet thanks, I will accept in 7 minutes apparently!